# CSS3: Detecting device orientation for iPhone

Tags: iphone, css

So this declaration works fine for iOS 4 and 4.1, but not for older versions.  Any advice?

```
@media screen and (device-width:320px) and (orientation:portrait) {
    /* iPhone Portrait Styles Here*/
}

@media screen and (device-width:320px) and (orientation:landscape) {
    /* iPhone Landscape Styles Here*/
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. According to the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries#orientation):

> **orientation**
>
> *Value: landscape | portrait*
>
> *Media: visual*
>
> *Accepts min/max prefixes: no*
>
> Indicates whether the viewport is in landscape (the display is wider
>   than it is tall) or portrait (the display is taller than it is wide)
>   mode.
>
> **Example**
>
> To apply a style sheet only in portrait orientation:
>
> `@media all and (orientation: portrait) { ... }`
>
> **Note:** This value does
>   not correspond to actual device orientation. Opening the soft keyboard
>   on most devices in portrait orientation will cause the viewport to
>   become wider than it is tall, thereby causing the browser to use
>   landscape styles instead of portrait.

Answer (score 0):

we use javascript to do this, in a similar way to this:

[Can js/jQuery determine the orientation of the iPhone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323281/can-js-jquery-determine-the-orientation-of-the-iphone)