# How change css dinamically by orientation device in ionic/angular

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have two button icon that change position depending on the screen orientation (landscape or portrait), how do I always have icons in the same position?

CSS

```
a#spunta.icon:before { 
  margin-left: 14em; color: green; transform: translate3d(0px,0px,0px) !important;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px,0px,0px) !important; 
}
a#spunta.icon-left:before { 
  margin-left: 4em; color: green; transform: translate3d(0px,0px,0px) !important;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px,0px,0px) !important; 
}


a#spuntaRif.icon:before { 
  transform: translate3d(0px,0px,0px) !important;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px,0px,0px) !important; 
}
a#spuntaRif.icon-left:before { 
  transform: translate3d(0px,0px,0px) !important;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0px,0px,0px) !important; 
}
```

HTML

```
div style="border-top: 1px solid #FF6600; border-bottom: 1px solid #FF6600;"> 
a class="button button-icon icon ion-checkmark-circled" id="spunta" ng-click="updateApprovata();goArchive();goDettaglio()">
/a>
a class="button button-icon icon ion-close-circled" id="spuntaRif" ng-click="updateRifiutata();goArchive();goDettaglio()">
/a> 
/div>
```

Comment: Have a look at this - should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789129/css3-detecting-device-orientation-for-iphone

Comment: media screen and (orientation:landscape) {}
media screen and (orientation:portrait) {}

in the css