# iPhone orientation HTML hiding

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, ios

Is there a way using JavaScript to hide a div element, when the iphone changes to portrait mode?

Comment: One of my own, [previous questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2323281/can-js-jquery-determine-the-orientation-of-the-iphone), might be worth a quick read.

Answer (score 1):

```
@media all and (orientation:portrait){
    #divID {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Pop that in your CSS ;-)

Answer (score 0):

you could do a lil js "trick":

```
var elem = document.getElementById('elemID');
window.onorientationchange = function(){
    if(document.body.offsetWidth == 960){ //don't remember the best way to retrieve body width atm
        elem.style.display = "none";      
    }else{
        elem.style.display = "block";   
    }
}
```